# Check if Text widget has been modified

Tags: perl, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, perltk

I have a **Button** and a **Text Widget**. When a user click the **Button**, I want to know if the text in the **Text Widget** has been modified since the last time the user clicked the **Button**.

How do I check this?

Comment: Save the text at each button press and compare it to the snapshot of the previous button press?

Comment: I know that method, but is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invocation

```
$t edit modified
```

(where `t` holds the pathname of your text widget) should tell you if the text widget has been modified.  Reset with

```
$t edit modified false
```

or whatever the corresponding Perl-Tk is.